# Conditioning on Two Variables

Tags: conditional-expectation

Does the following equality hold true?

$E[Z|\{X,Z\}] = Z$

If not, then when will it hold true?

Comment: @Anthony Conditional expectation is a random variable: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Formal_definition.

Comment: I think the first equality only holds if $X$ and $Z$ are independent.

Comment: That is my thinking as well but I hate to admit that you could have convinced me otherwise.  Thanks for the response.  I would have thought that the sigma algebra generated {X, Z} contains just as much information as the sigma algebra generated by Z.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, no, it always holds. Just because Z inside is completely determined by Z we're conditioning on.

Comment: @Kjetil Could you explain further?  I'm not exactly sure what this notation really means, but I would understand something like "$E[Z|Z,Z]$" to be identical to "$E[Z|Z]$" and that would seem to contradict what you assert, since $Z$ and $Z$ are as non-independent as you can get! I would have taken "$X,Z$" to refer to the smallest sigma algebra containing the algebras generated by *both* variables, whereas your remark seems to imply a different interpretation.

Comment: Taking a specific example for the moment, we're asking "*What's the expected weight of the cat, given that we know both that the dog weighs 4 pounds and the cat weighs 3 pounds?*", right? This seems ... not very difficult. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Glen_b X and Z are clearly independent in your example.  But what if X and Z are not independent variables?  I think the equality still holds but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: The weight of the dog and the weight of the cat are *not independent*, since I overfeed them both. But if you want a different dependent example, make $X$ "the volume of the cat" (highly correlated with weight). It doesn't matter *what* that value is, if I know the cat weighs 3 pounds *that's what it weighs*.

Comment: The additional information in $X$ may tell us we have an unusually *dense* cat (if the volume was surprisingly small given the correlation), but it won't change the expected weight, which is always 3 pounds. Since we already know what the cat weighs; the known values of other variables don't change that, even pretty highly correlated ones.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is always true. We condition on the value of $Z$ so that means we know the value of $Z$, there is no randomness left. That we also condition on $X$ is irrelevant.

To be more formal (see Probability with Martingales, Chapter 9, section 2, for example) the definition of conditional expectation is:

Consider sub-sigma algebra G, (here $\sigma\{X, Y\}$), then, $Y = \mathbb{E}(Z \mid G)$ iff

1. $Y$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable
2. $\mathbb{E}|Y| < \infty$
3. $\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{1}_g Y) = E(\mathbb{1}_g Z)$ for all $g$ in $\mathcal{G}$ (where $\mathbb{1}_g$ is the indicator function of $g$).

Clearly, $Z$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, and (3) holds trivially. Hence, as long as $\mathbb{E}|Z| < \infty$, $Z = \mathbb{E}(Z \mid X, Z)$.